# How to get a group value from grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I need to get a value from the `grep` command. For example:

`netstat -ntlp | grep 8000`

Output:

`tcp6  0   0 :::8000  ::: LISTEN  975/(squid-1)`

I want to get 975 from the output, so I used this command again:

`netstat -ntlp | grep 8000 | grep -oP '\d{1,4}\/'`

This is the result:

`975/`

Then if I want to get 975 in one command, I should use this:

`netstat -ntlp | grep 8000 | grep -oP '\d{1,4}\/' | grep -oP '\d{1,4}'`

This will get what I want [975], but I don't want to use `grep -oP | grep -oP`. Can I use `grep -oP` and group(1) like this:

`netstat -ntlp | grep 8000 | grep -oP '(\d{1,4})\/' | grop(1)` to get 975?

Can someone tell me how to get a group value in `grep`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
echo 'tcp6  0   0 :::8000  ::: LISTEN  975/(squid-1)' | grep -oP '\d{1,4}(?=\/)'
```

Comment: Can I use one grep mach 975 like:  `netstat -ntlp | grep -oP '(?<=8000.*)\d{1,4}(?=\/)'`   ?